# Does $\partial V \subset U$ imply $V \subset U$?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $U,V$ be two connected, bounded open sets in the plane, and assume that $\partial V \subset U$, where $\partial V$ is the boundary of $V$.

Is it true that $V \subset U$?

This seems true and this seems easy, but I can't seem to come up with a proof.

Note that the assumption that $V$ is bounded is necessary, otherwise we could take e.g. $U=\mathbb D$ and $V=\mathbb C^*$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try
$$
U = \{z : 1<|z|<3\}\\
V = \{z : |z|<2\}
$$
Show $\partial V \subset U$ but $V \not\subset U$.

---

Now try with hypothesis "simply connected".

Comment: thanks, I feel kind of stupid to have missed that!

Answer (score 1):

No, this does not follow.
As a counterexample consider $V$ to be the open unit disk and $U$ an open disk of radius larger than one with its center removed.
Then $\partial V = S^1 \subset U$ but $0 \in V \setminus U$.

It might work, if you require $U$ to have "no holes" i.e. if $U$ is simply connected.